# D2: std.algorithm.indexOf doesn't work anymore

Tags: d

I posted the following code on rosettacode.org for the task of [converting Arabic and Roman numerals](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#D).

```
import std.regex, std.array, std.algorithm;

immutable {
    int[] weights = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
    string[] symbols = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", 
                        "V", "IV", "I"];
}

string toRoman(int n) {
    auto app = appender!string;
    foreach (i, w; weights) {
        while (n >= w) {
            app.put(symbols[i]);
            n -= w;
        }
        if (n == 0) break;
    }
    return app.data;
}

int toArabic(string s) {
    int arabic;
    foreach (m; match(s, "CM|CD|XC|XL|IX|IV|[MDCLXVI]")) {
        arabic += weights[symbols.indexOf(m.hit)];
    }
    return arabic;
}
```

It used to work just fine, but now I get a compiler error.

> Error: template
>   std.algorithm.indexOf(alias pred = "a
>   == b",R1,R2) if (is(typeof(startsWith!(pred)(haystack,needl
>   e)))) does not match any function
>   template declaration

According to the documentation indexOf is deprecated, and countUntil should be used in stead, but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story but I'll try to keep it short:

`std.algorithm.indexOf` expects an [input range](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_range.html#isInputRange), which is a [structural type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) that must define `front`, `popFront()` and `empty`.  For arrays, these methods are [defined in std.array](http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_array.html#empty) and work via uniform function call syntax, which allows `fun(someArray)` to work the same as `someArray.fun()`.

`immutable string[]` is not an input range, since `popFront` removes the first element of the array, which cannot be done for an immutable type.  The fact that this used to work was a bug.

I've updated the Rosetta Code entry to change `symbols` to an `immutable(string)[]`.  Here, the elements of `symbols` are immutable, but the array may be sliced and reassigned.  For example:

```
void main() {
    immutable string[] s1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
    immutable(string)[] s2 = ["d", "e", "f"];

    s2 = s2[1..$];  // This is what std.array.popFront does under the hood.
    assert(s2 == ["e", "f"]);  // Passes.
    s2[1] = "g";     // Error:  Can't modify immutable data.

    s1 = s1[1..$];  // Error:  Can't modify immutable data.
    s1[1] = "g";    // Error:  Can't modify immutable data.
}
```

`immutable string[]` is implicitly convertible to `immutable(string)[]` but implicit function template instantiation (often denoted IFTI; this is what's used to instantiate the `indexOf` template) is not smart enough try this.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to get the index of an element in an immutable collection, or should I encapsulate the arrays, make them private, create accessors and roll my own indexOf?

Comment: @fwend:  Right now the easiest way is to convert it to head mutable.  For example:  `immutable(string)[] headMutable = symbols;`, then do what you need to do with `headMutable` instead of `symbols`.

Comment: Do you know of any proposals to fix this? Not being able to use `indexOf` on an immutable array is a pretty big problem.

Comment: @PeterAlexander: One can use slice operator: `symbols[]` have a type `immutable(string)[]` so just use `indexOf(symbols[])`

Comment: Also this is a common issue and fixed now "by automatically shedding the top-level const when passing an array or a pointer by value into a function": [Fixing const arrays](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/Fixing_const_arrays_151495.html)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a bug in `std.algorithm`. If you remove the `immutable` qualifier, the code works as is. I *think* `indexOf`/`countUntil` should work on `immutable` arrays, but at the moment it does not.

You can make them manifest constants (precede each declaration with `enum`) and it appears to work. [Amusingly, this may also be a bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2414).

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the breakage; I introduced it. I concur with dsimcha's description and proposed fix.

We are considering a simple change to the language to account for this simple case. That would automatically peel off one level of qualifiers when passing a value of a qualified type into a function. By that (for now hypothetical) rule, qualifier(T[]) would become (when passed to a function) qualifier(T)[] and qualifier(T*) would become qualifier(T)*. This would allow your example to work. The disadvantage is that a function would not be able to distinguish the top-level qualifier but I believe that that does not harm any concrete use.

Comment: How would this work with `class` types and `struct`s passed by `ref`? You can't just peel off an `immutable` otherwise the immutable object suddenly becomes mutable inside the function. This hypothetical rule smells fishy and sounds like the kind of thing that will cause problems later on in subtle ways.

Comment: @Peter: First, there is an experimental patch written by Michel Fortin that introduces mutable references to immutable class objects. Second, people tend to store immutable arrays as e.g. static tables quite often, but wouldn't ordinarily manipulate an immutable general range. That being said, I agree a more general rule would be desirable.